# how to detect invalid commands being passed into create process

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, createprocess

I am currently working on a program that starts a program that is specified by the user. 
passed in is as a wstring entered in by the user. My question is how do i make it throw an exception or check if "passedIn" is vaild. Currently, if the user enters in "notepad.exe" it launches it properly but if they enter somthing bogus like "asdf" or something along those lines it still creates the process.

```
try {
    wchar_t* commandLine = new wchar_t [CP_MAX_COMMANDLINE];
    wcsncpy_s(commandLine, CP_MAX_COMMANDLINE, passedIn.c_str(), passedIn.size() +1);
    CreateProcess(NULL, 
        commandLine, 
        NULL, NULL,
        false,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,
        NULL,
        &sinfo,
        &pi);

    delete [] commandLine;
}
catch (int e) {
    cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << endl;
}
```

I was hopeing my catch would grab it but it doesnt. Is there anything i can do to check if its vaild?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [function's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) (which should have been the first thing you checked):

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx).

So, check the function's return value.

Comment: perfect! thanks, I was using the getLastError for when my program randomly crashed. I have to wait another 6 mins before i can mark this as the right answer.